# 64 bit registers in Protected Mode x86

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, bare-metal, protected-mode

I was wondering am I able to use 64 bit registers on 64 bit processor when staying in 32 bit Protected mode. I cannot test this myself as my virtual machines doesn't support 64 bit long mode. I also couldn't found this anywhere in Internet. I thought that this may be possible due to fact that 32 bit registers can be used in 16 bit real mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't.

64-bit registers are only available in their full width in 64-bit mode. I couldn't find an explicit quote mentioning the fact that their usage from 32-bit mode is not possible, but this should be sufficient ([Basic Architecture, section 3.4.1.1](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-1-manual.pdf)) :

> Because the upper 32 bits of 64-bit general-purpose registers are
>   undefined in 32-bit modes, the upper 32 bits of any general-purpose
>   register are not preserved when switching from 64-bit mode to a 32-bit
>   mode (to protected mode or compatibility mode). Software must not
>   depend on these bits to maintain a value after a 64-bit to 32-bit mode
>   switch.

32-bit registers are accessible from within 16-bit mode thanks to the operand size override prefix (`0x66`). Basically, it tells the CPU to use a 32-bit register instead of a 16-bit one, which is the default in 16-bit mode. The prefix can also be used in 32-bit mode, but works the opposite way : it instructs the CPU to use a 16-bit register instead of a default 32-bit one.